# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in windows service

Tags: c#

Read a app.config value:

```
string configFile = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"].ToString();
```

Config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="connStr" value="Data Source=Dolphin-PC;
                              Initial Catalog=jsptpd_SYS;
                              Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;
                              Password=ccir"/>
</appSettings>
```

Get an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

the \program   and debug\ folder contains app.config file.

Comment: Split the line to find `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"]` first - I expect you'll find it's null. If so, you need to ask a different question.

Comment: Is your `app.config` file added in same project as your startUp project? This will return null only in case file not present in output path of your project.

Comment: check your appsettings anything it is wrong

Comment: why are storing a connection string in appSettings? why don't you store it in the ConnectionStrings element and access it with ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[x].ConnectionString.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why woud this happen

Because, `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStr"]` is null

> How could i deal it?

A more valid question. There isn't anything wrong with your code here. the main reason that you are finding it null is probably because your app.config is not present in the directory you are running the application from. It could be because app.config is part of some library and it is not copied to the output directory. You need to make sure that either app.config is in your main project or you copy it to the directory (you are running your applicatior from) explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

To fixed the problem,you need to know the princeple of ConfigurationManager how to read the config file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

To solve this problem,you could make sure your bin/ directory generate **yourprogram.exe.config** file,so the ConfigurationManager could read.

If this file missing,you coud make sure your app.config attribute generate operation is not **Embeded resource**.If it is true,the app.config will embeded to the exe file and configurationmanager could not read.